# gauss' opinion on de moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

What did Gauss mean when he said that you'd never be a good mathematician if you didn't think that De Moivre's theorem was obvious? I'm looking for a specifically historically correct answer with evidence based on his letters, remarks, etc. & not a mathematical guess based on the properties of Taylor series, etc., which would be based on calculation & nothing that could be regarded as "obvious". Gauss was a deep guy; give me a deep answer. This may not be the right discussion forum for this question; please suggest another if you can.

Comment: "What did he mean?" may be off-topic.  But "Where did he say it?" certainly is not.  And, once we have that reference, maybe he also says why in the same place.